# Selecting a row in a DataGridView and having the arrow on the row header follow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, header-row

This is in C#. If I select a row in a DataGridView with DataGridViewRow.Selected = true, the row selects just fine, but the arrow in the "column header" (the grey very leftmost column) doesn't follow. How do I set that?

Another question: If I set a column format to "centered" in the designer, the column header is still left aligned. How do I set the column header to be centered too?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is straight from [google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Selecting+a+row+in+a+DataGridView+and+having+the+arrow+on+the+row+header+follow):

> In a DataGridView, the selected row and the current row (indicated by an 
> arrow in the row header) may not be the same row. In addition, we could 
> select multiple rows in a DataGridView but the current row can only be one 
> row.
>
> When the SelectionMode property of the DataGridView is set to 
> FullRowSelect, the current row will be always selected. 
>
> If you'd like to change the current row in a DataGridView control, you may 
> set the CurrentCell property

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0];
```

> If you'd like to just change the selected row, you may set the Selected 
> property of the row you want to true.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = false;
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of you question, make sure your setting the **header style** for the column to centered as well.